# Insert into with distinct (control duplicate ) one column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, greatest-n-per-group

Hello I have table with `15000 Records` I need insert other table Records without duplicate in one column

This is my sql:

```
INSERT INTO ceny_min2(id, idt, kod_k, nrdok, data_z, odczytano, ost_update, cena_min) 
SELECT * 
FROM cenymin 
WHERE id IN (
         SELECT MIN(id) 
         FROM cenymin 
         WHERE (SELECT distinct idt FROM cenymin)
    )
```

idt- is column which i need check and flip only first records.

Error:

```
ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer


********** Błąd **********

ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer
Stan SQL: 42804
```

Comment: Can you add sample data which would help to _explain_ what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: `where ??? in (select idt from cenymin)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent duplicates in your table, then you should do so with a unique constraint or index. Then, if you want to do an insert, you use `on conflict ignore`:

```
insert into ceny_min2 (id, idt, kod_k, nrdok, data_z, odczytano, ost_update, cena_min) 
    select * 
    from cenymin 
    on conflict on constraint <unique constraint> do nothing;
```

I would suggest particular syntax, but I cannot figure out what you really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want:

```
insert into ceny_min2(id, idt, kod_k, nrdok, data_z, odczytano, ost_update, cena_min) 
select id, idt, kod_k, nrdok, data_z, odczytano, ost_update, cena_min
from cenymin c
where c.id = (select min(id) from cenymin c1 where c1.idt = c.idt)
```

This gives you the row with the smaller `id` for each `idt`.

You can also express this with window functions:

```
insert into ceny_min2(id, idt, kod_k, nrdok, data_z, odczytano, ost_update, cena_min) 
select id, idt, kod_k, nrdok, data_z, odczytano, ost_update, cena_min
from (
    select c.*, row_number() over(partition by idt order by id) rn
    from cenymin c
) c
where rn = 1
```

Or with `distinct on`:

```
insert into ceny_min2(id, idt, kod_k, nrdok, data_z, odczytano, ost_update, cena_min) 
select distinct on (idt) id, idt, kod_k, nrdok, data_z, odczytano, ost_update, cena_min
from cenymin c
order by idt, id
```

Comment: Thanks i have reasult which i want :) !